# the table view cells not release from memory

Tags: swift3, uitableview

i hope all is well
i have an issue with cell in table view it's not releasing when i scrolling in table view the following is my code

```
class MovieDownloadedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var movieImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var movieNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var movieEmptyCircleImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var movieCheckMarkImageView: UIImageView!

    var fetchURL:URL? {
        didSet {
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    func updateUI() {

        movieImageView.image = nil
        movieNameLabel.text = nil
        movieEmptyCircleImageView.isHidden = true
        movieCheckMarkImageView.isHidden = true
        if let fetchURL = fetchURL {
            if fetchURL.pathExtension == "" {
               movieImageView.image = UIImage(named: "folder")
            }else{
               movieImageView.image = UIImage(named: "movie")
            }
            movieNameLabel.text = fetchURL.lastPathComponent

        }// end the if let

    }// end the func updateUI

}// end the class
```

the above my custom table view cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? MovieDownloadedTableViewCell

    // defining the cell
    if let cell = cell {
        cell.tintColor = UIColor.white
        cell.fetchURL = operationDocumentDirectoryObject.arrayOfMovieURL?[indexPath.row]

        if isShowToolBar {

        if operationDocumentDirectoryObject?.arrayOfShowAllEmptyCircle?[indexPath.row] == indexPath.row {
            cell.movieEmptyCircleImageView.isHidden = false
            }// end the if

            if operationDocumentDirectoryObject.dictionaryHoldIndexCellForDisplayWhichCellSelected.count > 0 {
                if operationDocumentDirectoryObject.dictionaryHoldIndexCellForDisplayWhichCellSelected[indexPath.row] == indexPath.row {
                    cell.movieEmptyCircleImageView.isHidden = true
                    cell.movieCheckMarkImageView.isHidden = false
                }
            }

        }// end if for the isShowVar

    }// end the creating cell

    return cell!
}
```

please where my wrong code how can i make my table view cell when i scrolling is releasing from memory every time

thank you very much